# Searching for documentation on operators with SPECIAL characters

Tags: r, documentation

I have seen in a course the use of `%--%` as an operator.

From context, it is some sort of piecewise subtraction of the elements of two vectors. However, vectors operate that way natively from what I understand. I want to find the documentation on this operator so that I can understand it more.  I have looked up the operators in base R and I can not find it listed. It appears that it comes from a package rather than base R.

`?%--%` returns

> Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "?%--%"

Trying to escape the specials does not lead to joy.
Given that the operator is largely a collection of special characters google searches do not bear fruit either. How can I search for help on such a cypher?

Comment: I actually do not get that error, though I'm using emacs/ess and not the RStudio IDE (or Rterm). However, it can sometimes be useful to see in which package(s) that or similar function names are listed, so `help.search("%--%")` for me lists `igraph::igraph-es-indexing` (has an alias of `%--%`) and `lubridate::interval` (ditto). From there, `?lubridate::%--%` (or whichever package/version you want) _should_ work, at least it does for me.

Comment: I _can_ reproduce that error when I try to source a line from a `.R` file. That is, when I initially tried `?%--%`, it was on the console itself. When I have a line in a `.R` file with that text, and then "step" that expression into the R process (I forget what RStudio calls that mechanism), I do get the error. So ... I never use `?` or `??` commands from a source file, I don't know why that would ever be more useful than (say) typing it directly in the console.

Comment: THe problem is you need to use back ticks not quotation marks. "?`%--%/`"  but not with the ""

Comment: @Elin, does that actually work for you? It does not work for me (though I'm using emacs/ess, not RStudio, not sure if the IDE would be performing differently in this way). (BTW, it's usually better to backslash escape your backticks in comments, where typing `?\\`%--%\\`` should produce `?\`%--%\`` in the comment.

Comment: YEs it does; I'm in RStudio.     This is how to get help also on items like "?`+ `" .  Well it won't let me format the way I want in a comment

Comment: Odd, okay. For me, `?+` works (and `?%--%`, when its package is loaded). Thanks.

Comment: Interesting!  I think it must be because you are using emacs.

Comment: @Elin, your quotes around the operator worked, if you want to write it up as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Avoid the `?` shortcut and get in the habit of using `help("%--%")`.